# Ghost touch on android device only when connected

Tags: android, macbook, ios, touchscreen

A couple of weeks ago I started noticing some ghost touch on my android device. Initially was not very often and it didn't cause a big problem, but recently started to be really annoying.

Doing some research I found out that it happens only when connected to a cable (I tried more cables with the same results) and specifically when connected to a laptop.

I then tried an ipad and another android on the same laptop (a macbook), and it seems that only the ipad have the same bad behaviour. Then I tried to switch laptop (to a windows one) with my android and it seems to work perfectly.

The only common thing that I notice in all of this is that the problem seems to be present only on the macbook. Another thing that could matter is that I am a mobile developer and I use both my android and the ipad to test app, while the other android I tried was never used for this purpose.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I had similar happen when I was plugged into a half-rectified power supply. In my case that was a combination of an in-car 12v inverter to 240v, then the regular 240-5v mains charger. The only 'fix' was to just not do that. [I could have maybe found a fully-rectified inverter, but it wasn't worth the effort for the use-case.]

Comment: Well, I did not expect this to work, but using the macbook without charger and using only the battery seems to do the job, and probably it's something related to your problem. Thank you very much, I needed it (I can not upvote the comment sorry, I think I'm missing some reputation)

Comment: I can throw it into an answer, but it's going to be a bit vague. idk exactly what causes it, but I could always repro it reliably, any time a capacitive-touch device was plugged into that inverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dropping to answer space just for sake of completeness...*

I had similar happen when I was plugged into a [half-rectified power supply](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html). In my case that was a combination of an in-car 12v inverter to 240v, then the regular 240-5v mains charger. The only 'fix' was to just not do that. [I could have maybe found a fully-rectified inverter, but it wasn't worth the effort for the use-case.]

idk exactly what causes it, but I could always repro it reliably, any time a capacitive-touch device was plugged into that inverter.

The only thing further I could suggest to test would be the earthing/grounding on your mains supply & laptop PSU.

Comment: I mark this as correct as to me it seems to be a problem related to my charger